# Launch Android application from a button click on a webpage from mobile browser .. develop a plugin

Tags: android

The basic objective of this implementation is originally a file was uploaded to  a specific file server location using Android application. On successful upload , an e-mail with Download button(on the web page) was sent to the user. I want to provide the user the functionality of first dowloading & then uploading the file to a different file server location using my Android app.

**Steps**

i> Opened a web page from the mobile browser of the device & clicked on a download button.

ii> Download button normally downloads the zip file to the SDCard of the mobile device.
But , I want to provide a different functionality when the user clicks on the Download button.

List of options is displayed to the user :

a>Store to SDCard

b>my Android application (Android is already installed on the device)

When the user clicks on the Store to SDCard option , then automatically the zip file will be stored on the SDCard. But if the user clicks on my android application , the application will launch & move to a specific screen . On that screen , I will have an a button which will have option to save the zip file to a file server.

When the user clicks on the button , first I need to download the zip file to a temp folder on the SDCard of the device & then upload that to a different file server location.

Any hints/suggestions on development of this plugin will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at android url schemes. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser) SO question. Might help you.